# spacemacs line number - 0.999.x version

Tags: spacemacs

Just installed spacemacs.  I am familiar with vim. I opened the spacemacs dot file by space f e d.  I've updated the file with

```
dotspacemacs-line-numbers '(:relative t
                            :disabled-for-modes dired-mode
                                                doc-view-mode
                                                pdf-view-mode
                            :size-limit-kb 1000)
```

Unfortunately above setting does not work on any text file I open.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

i reinstalled everything and updated the config file as is.  it's now working.